# Onchange cannot get the correct value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem to get the value in the input for onchange function. Below is my coding:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Choose Book:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
 <select class="form-control" id="publisher" name="publisher" title="publisher">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <?php
 $sql_branch = 'select * from book_lending where status=1 order by id';
 $arr_branch = db_conn_select($sql_branch);
 foreach ($arr_branch as $rs_branch) {
 echo '<option value="' . $rs_branch['id'] . '">' . $rs_branch['title'] . '</option>';
 }
 ?>
</select>
  </div>


 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="cp1" class="control-label">Book Stock<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
 <input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor" title="editor" value="" >
 </div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#publisher").change(function(){
        var displayid=$("#publisher option:selected").text();
        $("editor").val(displayid);
    })
})
</script>
```

Below is output picture:

[image: Output 1]

I need to show the input value if I onchange in the id is publisher, then id editor will show the value.Hope someone can guide me which part I get the wrong. Thanks.

Comment: $("#editor").val(displayid); Only change this

Comment: `$("editor")` typo missing `#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:-**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#publisher").change(function(){
        var value=$("#publisher").val();
        $("#editor").val(value);
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I just get the value="' . $rs_branch['id'] show in the input. Now the value is show $rs_branch['title']

Comment: I have other question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905902/how-to-get-the-second-value-in-the-id-to-make-onchange-function If you have time can help me to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing editor id

```
$(function(){
    $("#publisher").change(function(){
        var displayid=$(this).val();
        $("#editor").val(displayid);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I just get the value="' . $rs_branch['id']  show in the input. Now the value is show $rs_branch['title']

Comment: I have other question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905902/how-to-get-the-second-value-in-the-id-to-make-onchange-function If you have time can help me to check. Thanks.